# Error while calling the Java Script Adapter procedure in MFP V8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am migrating my App from MFP V 7.1 to MFP V 8.0. I have following scenario in which I am constructing a data object and sending the request to the MFP adapter from my client using below code:

```
function SearchData(username,name,city){
    this.username = username;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
}


searchData(){
    var searchData = new SearchData(getUserId(),name,city);
    var dataRequest = new WLResourceRequest('/adapters/MyAdapterName/searchEmployer', WLResourceRequest.GET);
    alert('there');
    dataRequest.send(searchData).then(
            function(response){
                console.log('response --> ' + response);
            },
            function(){
                console.log('error response --> ' );
            }
    );
}
```

Below is the code written in my java script adapter:

```
function searchData(searchData){
    try{
        WL.Logger.info("Inside searchData() method.");
        var input = {
                method              : 'post',
                returnedContentType : 'json',
                path                : 'rest/search',
                body                : {
                    contentType : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    content     : JSON.stringify(searchData)
                }

        };
        var response = MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
        return response;
    }catch(exception){
        WL.Logger.error("Inside searchData() method :: " + exception.message);
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Every time when I am calling this method, the failure function is getting called. I also tried to send the request using [sendFormParameters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html) method but it is returning printing following error:

```
worklight.js:9342 Uncaught Error: Invalid invocation of method WLResourceRequest.sendFormParameters; Form value must be a simple type.
logAndThrowError @ worklight.js:9342
encodeFormParameters @ worklight.js:9727
WLResourceRequest.sendFormParameters @ 
worklight.js:9685searchEmployer @ VM79:47
onclick @ index.html:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That issue occurs when the object you are passing contains nested objects or is of type function.

In your case you have multiple variables/functions with the same name `searchData`, `SearchData`. I'll recommend you change the names to be more descriptive.

I've tried the following and it runs successfully

```
function SearchData(username,name,city){
    this.username = username;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
}


function search(){
    var data = new SearchData(getUserId(), name, city);
    var request = new WLResourceRequest('/adapters/MyAdapterName/searchEmployer', WLResourceRequest.GET);
    request.send(searchData).then(function(response){
      console.log('response --> ', response);
    }, function(error){
      console.log('error response --> ', error);
    });
}
```

If you are still having problems after running the code above, share a link with your project or add more code snippets.

**UDPATE:**

For Javascript adapters receive their parameters via a GET variable `params`, `params`is an array of parameters.

So you'll need to update your code in the client as follow:

```
function search(){
    var data = new SearchData(getUserId(), name, city);
    var request = new WLResourceRequest('/adapters/MyAdapterName/searchEmployer', WLResourceRequest.GET);
    request.setQueryParameter("params", [JSON.stringify(data)]);
    request.send().then(function(response){
      console.log('response --> ', response);
    }, function(error){
      console.log('error response --> ', error);
    });
}
```

Since the data passed to the adapter is a sting the you need to update your adapter procedure to reflect that i.e., remove `JSON.stringify`

```
function searchData(payload){
    try{
        WL.Logger.info("Inside searchData() method.");
        var input = {
                method              : 'post',
                returnedContentType : 'json',
                path                : 'rest/search',
                body                : {
                    contentType : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    content     : payload
                }

        };
        var response = MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
        return response;
    }catch(exception){
        WL.Logger.error("Inside searchData() method :: " + exception.message);
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: The adapter method is getting called now. However the change which I made was I had audit="true" inside <procedure name="searchEmployer" secured="false"/> which was causing some some problem. But I still made the changes suggested by you and once call reaches in the adapter method I am getting the function argument as 'undefined'. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari read the update to the answer, I address that issue there

Comment: @Yoel...it worked for me...I tried using setQueryParameter method before posting the comment but the problem was that I was passing the data in method argument without brackets ([]). That's  why it did not worked for me.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: @Yoel...can you point me to the documentation from where you get the syntax of "setQueryParameter" method?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari for JS the parameters are passed via the `params` query parameter as an array and that is the only reason why you need the square brackets. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_adapters_endpoint.html